# Renaming a field "RefernceName" in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I need to change a field "RefrenceName" in tfs, there is `witadmin changefield` command but it only renames friendly name not "ReferenceName".

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, its not possible to change the ReferenceName attribute.